# Nbitcoin.Transaction inaccessible due to protection level C#

Tags: c#, bitcoin, nbitcoin

Using the NBitcoin library I am trying to make a transaction, when calling

```
Transaction tx = new Transaction { };
```

I get the error Transaction.Transaction() is inaccessible due to its protection level. Renaming it to NBitcoin.Transaction results in the same thing. I've been looking but cant find a way to invoke a transaction without using the transaction function nor can I figure out why it is being protected because the same code seems to work for other people.

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin.Docs/blob/master/README.md / https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/Transaction.cs#L1316

Comment: I read https://programmingblockchain.gitbook.io/programmingblockchain/ and some other sites but havent looked at the github yet Ill read through those now

Comment: What prevents you from using one of the static methods in the Transaction class instead, such as `public static Transaction Create(Network network)`?

Comment: Was looking at the transaction builder but even then you need to define by creating a new transaction https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835098/NBitcoin-Build-Them-All


`Transaction aliceFunding = new Transaction()
{
    Outputs =
    {
        new TxOut("0.45", alice.GetAddress()),
        new TxOut("0.8", alice.Key.PubKey)
    }
};`

Comment: That article is from 2014. I suspect the project has changed in the last 6 years.

Comment: Did you try calling the method that @RobertHarvey and I suggested?

Comment: I tried it but there's no "Create" to call

Comment: Yes there is. `Transaction.Create`. If there isn't, do a NuGet update to the latest package.

Comment: I only have access to `Transaction.LockTimeFlags` no other methods under transaction because of the protection level (on newest version)

Answer (score -1):

I just kept downgrading until a version worked not the best fix but works for now I'll use newer methods once more of their docs are updated :p